# Why hadoop slave cannot run a job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, containers, jobs, hadoop-yarn

I run a YARN mapreduce job with 1 node.

But my job stuck on ACCEPTED state, and still 0% completed. I checked with jps command on my slave, there is no MR App Master or YARN Child to complete the job. On my slave all daemons have ran normally like datanode and nodemanager. There is no wrong configuration on my master node, because I've tried t before with different slave and it's works.

How can I fix it? Thanks....

Comment: Are you able to see your slave node on hadoop cluster UI (may be on master:8080)? Check if your master-slave configuration is Ok. Also see the slave's logs

Comment: I cannot see on master:8080 cause I opened it by remote ssh not remote desktop. So, I checked it on yarn application -list command and it show ACCEPTED state and 0% progress. Cause the job not started yet, logs on slave is empty...do you know why like this?

Comment: I think the slave files on etc/hadoop is the configuration for slave to do mapreduce job too...